# In ADF Page refresh

Tags: java, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have three tables in a page. When I click on a button, I update only one of the tables. But since I use request scope on button event, the page reloads fully and updated value gets lost. Can you suggest a solution, so that my data will be displayed after button event.

Comment: I suppose setting immediate to true doesn't meet your requirements?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to set  partialSubmit="true" in your button? If you set this attribute, you must  set in each table a PartialTriggers to the button.

I hope help you.

Marcos.

Answer (score 0):

The data has to be in the viewScope/pageFlowScope depending on whether its in a bounded taskFlow or not.

And in your button event you need to update the data in the viewScope/pageFlowScope and then bind your tables with those data.

All the event handlers can be in backingBean scope and not necessarily be in requestScope.